# How to remove row numbering in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I read first 3 rows of csv file from link using pandas library with below code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(url, nrows=3)
print(data)
```

it returns:
[image: book_dataset_image]

But I don't want the row numbering like `0 1 2`

**How should I remove them?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Pandas need an index to your rows and columns. Maybe you can define `book_id` column as index row:

```
data = pd.read_csv(url, index_col='book_id', nrows=3)
```

**Update**

> Basically, I want to convert data to json so if I shouldn't remove row numbering, data.to_json() returns {"book_id":{"0":1},"goodreads_book_id":{"0":2767052} ... . But I want it like this: { "book_id":1, "goodreads_book_id":2767052, ...... Is there other way to do it?

```
data = pd.read_csv(url, nrows=3)
out = df.to_json(orient='records', indent=4)
print(out)

# Output
[
    {
        "book_id":15,
        "goodreads_book_id":111
    },
    {
        "book_id":16,
        "goodreads_book_id":112
    }
]
```

Comment: Basically, I want to convert data to json so if I shouldn't remove row numbering, ```data.to_json()``` returns ```{"book_id":{"0":1},"goodreads_book_id":{"0":2767052} ...``` . But I want it like this: ```{ "book_id":1, "goodreads_book_id":2767052, .....```. Is there other way to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @EltacShikhsaidov. I updated my answer. Can your check it please?